# Html Agility Pack Ampersand Bug ( <title>Google Adwords&amp;trade;</title> )

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using html agility pack to parse html tags and have problems with

Google Adwords&trade; - **see title**

In title the user has put in an & and we convert it and gets amp.

I have tried to replace amp with space without success:

```
 var sTitle = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//title");

            sTitle.Replace("amp").("")
```

How do i do?

Comment: It's not clear whether you're reading or writing the HTML.  Can you be more precise about what you are doing, and what your expected inputs and outputs are? `&` is a special character so the representation of the text `&` uses the entity `&amp;` (this will be rendered as `&`).

Comment: The result i want is Google Adwords&trade

Comment: I'm reading the HTML and want to rewrite the string without amp

Comment: Its not sensible to expect HTML Agility Pack to allow you to make invalid HTML. `&` alone, is not valid HTML.

Comment: i agree it's not valid HTML but it is what the user has written in title tag...

Answer (score 2):

Not that clear what your problem is, but assuming you are asking how to properly read html-encoded text (such as & character in its html encoding which is `&amp;` (see [this](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for a list of html codes and the character they represent),

you need to use System.Net.HttpUtility's HtmlDecode function.

See the following demo:

```
        string s = "<title>Google Adwords&amp;trade;</title>";

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(s);

        var titleNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title");

        //prints Google Adwords&amp;trade;
        Console.WriteLine(titleNode.InnerText);

        //prints Google Adwords&trade;
        Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(titleNode.InnerText));
```

Comment: Thanks, but have problem in Visual Studio 2010, doesn't have HttpUtility in System.Net ...

Comment: When you want to refer to a dll that is not included/referenced in your project, you need to [include it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). In your case, you want to add the System.Net dll.